# UICollectionViewDelegate shouldSelectItemAt not called

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit

Event based methods of my delegate are not called while others are called.  For example, `willDisplayCell` is called, but `shouldHighlightItemAt` and `shouldSelectItemAt` are not called.  I overwrote `point(inside:...)` method inside my custom `UICollectionView`, and it gets called and `super` returns true.  What could be causing this?  I'm on iOS 11.4, Swift 4.1, and Xcode 9.4.1.

Comment: post code .........

Comment: the code is too big

Comment: the questions is: what are the possible reasons for this?  Clearly the delegate is set because some methods are called.  The view is visible and appropriate size because the point method is hit.  So, what could be the cause of this?

Comment: allowsSelection is set to true in the collection view.  I am using a custom layout which creates layout attributes for all cells.  The frame, bounds, and size of the attributes are set correctly.

Comment: share a demo of the problem

Comment: The issue appears to reside internally in the collection view of processing the point event into calling the delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a supplementary view to the collection view that spans the entire area of its bounds.  This view was intercepting all tap events.  Once I set its `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` I started receiving highlight and selection calls on cells in my delegate.